# How do I map a variable to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm new to JSON and jQuery/JavaScript.

How would I pull in a object so that I can use it within jQuery, I've tried 2 attempts

```
var placements = document.querySelector(placements)
var message = document.querySelector(placements.message)


$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kieranbs96/developer-exercise/master/data/recommendations.json',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    $("header").append(placements.message);
  }
});
```

Below is the JSON I'm trying to pull in:

```
{  
   "placements":[  
      {  
         "message":"If you like this, you might be into these",
         "items":[  
            {  
               "id":"029148",
               "name":"Woodblock Play Suit",
               "price":"46.00"
            },
            {  
               "id":"0294526806",
               "name":"Smock Dress",
               "price":"39.00"
            },
            {  
               "id":"0297180006",
               "name":"Cami",
               "price":"9.00"
            },
            {  
               "id":"0298473606",
               "name":"Asymmetric Wrap Cami Dress",
               "price":"46.00"
            },
            {  
               "id":"0297155306",
               "name":"Casual Stripe Tee",
               "price":"16.00"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Marked as duplicate - the other question did not solve my problem - it has been solved by an answer to this question.

Comment: You want to append the data to the DOM, I suppose. What should the result look like?

Comment: this would probably help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655008/how-to-get-json-field-names

Comment: That first line looks like a potential bug/issue: `var placements = document.querySelector(placements)`. What is `placements` before you query the DOM?

Comment: Looks good, you just forgot to use `data`.  `$("header").append(data.placements. .... )`

Comment: Your JSON data is in the variable `data` within the `success` callback. But without seeing your HTML it's hard to say what you should do with it.

Comment: Are you seeing any particular error?

Comment: What does *pull in a object*? Mean?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: side note : setting "async: false", is bad practice for ajax calls

Comment: What purpose are those first two variables supposed to serve?

Comment: It's not just bad practice, never ever set `async false`. If your struggling with async in javascript please read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: @KarthikGanesan & Liam - Thank you for the advise on async - this was recommended weirdly by mdn. - Liam what I mean is to display the object using jQuery - title made more sense than what I actually wrote! - There was no particular error it was more a question of what is best practice. Jeremy, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Liam - I am struggling to find answers to my questions on Stack Overflow, you seem to know the site quite well, my new question is this: I am now trying to add in the objects 'id' 'name' 'price', how would I do this, i've tried this: `$(".placements-items").append(data.placements[0].items.id);` - but no luck

Comment: Hi @KieranSmith. If you have a new question then you should ask it using the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @Liam was more asking on advice for searching as these seem like simple questions that i can't find answers too sorry for not making that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included what the error is or the expected output, but here's two potential errors.

1. You aren't utilizing the `data` object returned from your AJAX request.
2. The value associated with the `placements` key on your JSON object is an *array* of objects. Therefore, to access the `message` key, you'll need to traverse the array.

This is likely what your code should look like:

```
 $("header").append(data.placements[0].message);
```

Comment: Great - you've solved my problem, wasnt really an error it was more I wasn't sure how the above was actually done in the correct way, won't let me mark your answer as solved... sorry

Comment: @KieranSmith I think you have to wait 15 minutes or something like that before accepting an answer. As to your question from above about `id`, `name`, and `price`, keep in mind that the value of the `items` key is also an _array_ of objects. Meaning you'll have to traverse the array – something like `data.placements[0].items[0].id`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're missing the data object within your append function.
Second, you're missing the key notation of `data.placements` considering the fact that `placements` is an `array`.
You can either use `data.placements[0].message` to get your preferred data, or, if `placements` will be extended with more objects in the future, `map` through your objects like this:

```
    data.placements.map(function(obj, index){
        if(index == 0){
            $("header").append(obj.message);
        }
    })
```

Not necessary if your array will always have a length of 1 of course